# grub menu problem in windows 8 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

after install ubuntu 13.04 in pre installed windows 8 ,ubuntu is successfully installed   but every time i start the system windows boot loader show both   the os, in that windows 8 works perfectly but when i select ubuntu it will ask for windows 8  dvd  saying that this is  because of the other os installed in it giving 2 options at the bottom ends saying esc to select os  and enter to uefi boot and to select ubuntu i need to change my boot options to legacy suppot and legacy fisrt so that ill get grub menu of ubuntu but in that windows 8 loader doesnt work again saying that plz install dvd of windows 8 plz provide me a solution so that i could select both the os from any of the boot loaders.

Answer (score 2):

You have installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode and have Windows 8 in UEFI mode. The two boot modes are not really compatible. Once you start booting in one mode, you cannot switch to the other mode. So grub cannot boot UEFI  Windows once you start booting in BIOS mode.

You can either re-install in UEFI mode or use Boot-Repair to convert the Ubuntu install from BIOS to UEFI.

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Install with UEFI:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)