# Hp boot load failure

Tags: boot

I've installed Ubuntu on a partition on my hp. If i boot from cd it will let me boot to Ubuntu, but if i don't it boots automatically to windows without giving me the option to boot to Ubuntu. Suggestions?

Comment: Please advise which version of Windows you have, and whether it uses UEFI Boot. http://askubuntu.com/questions/364013/grub-menu-problem-in-windows-8-dual-boot explains why I'm askin'.

Answer (score 0):

When your computer turns on, it should start at a screen that has your computer's brand logo. At that screen, before windows starts to load, hit F12 rapidly. It should take you to a screen where you can select where to boot from. If F12 doesn't do anything, try F2.